# Passing parameter in crontab through shell to php script

Tags: php, shell, cron, cron-task

From my shell script **test.sh** I would like to pass some parameters to PHP script that would read them like:

**test.sh**

```
php -q /home/user/files/test.php "$1" "$2"
php -q /home/user/files/test.php $1 $2
```

To test the passing of arguments I just read them like this (**test.php**):

```
<?php
   echo 'Arg 1: ' . $argv[1] ."\n";
   echo 'Arg 2: ' . $argv[2] ."\n";
?>
```

Problem is, that if I run test.sh from shell with command:

```
./test.sh one two
```

my php script reads both parameters just fine (both times):

```
Arg 1: one
Arg 2: two
Arg 1: one
Arg 2: two
```

But if I run it via crontab it can't read parameters and I get only:

```
Arg 1: 
Arg 2: 
Arg 1: 
Arg 2:
```

Cron job looks like this:

```
20  13  *   *   *   /home/user/files/test.sh one two
```

How can I correctly pass arguments via a cron job to the shell script and thereafter to php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have `register_argc_argv` enabled in your php.ini.

Use php's `getopt` to get the command line arguments.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php

Answer (score 1):

if you can't change you php ini; you could probably set the option as a pram to php

```
php -q -d register_argc_argv=On /home/user/files/test.php "$1" "$2"
```

OR quote them in you bash script

```
php -q /home/user/files/test.php '$1' '$2'
```

and access them inside your script via global server

```
$foo=$_SERVER['argv'][1];
$bar=$_SERVER['argv'][2];
```